# My jQuery plugin always return Object object

Tags: jquery, object, return, return-value

I am writing a jQuery plugin but it is always returning Object object here is the code inside:

```
$.fn.plugin = function(options) {

            var defaults = {
             rules : []
            }    
            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function() {
                var o = options;
                var rules = o.rules;
                var i=0;
                var isValable = true;
                var string = "";
                for (i=0;i<=((rules.length)-1);i++)
                    {
                        $('.'+rules[i][0]).each(function(index) {
                            var val = $(this).val();
                            var $elm = $(this);
                            if(!(rules[i][2](val, $elm)))
                            {
                                if (!$elm.hasClass('validation-failed')) $elm.addClass('validation-failed');
                                $elm.after('<div class="validation-advice" id="advice-' + rules[i][0] + '-' + $elm.attr('id') +'" style="display:none">' + rules[i][1] + '</div>');
                                isValable = false;
                            }
                            else if (!$elm.hasClass('validation-passed')) $elm.addClass('validation-passed') ;
                        });
                    }
            return isValable;   
            });
        }
```

I get the Object object when calling `alert($('myselector').plugin())`
Thanks for your help

Comment: We need to see more code, how are you getting object object ? Are you using an alert ?

Comment: please give us more details to help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had problems because of the double return, removing the first one solved it !

Answer (score 0):

not sure if it's the problem because you didn't show how you're calling the plugin but it should be

```
return $(this).each(function()...
```

Comment: sorry this is totally wrong. I didn't realize until I read here more closely: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

From what I understand in that doc, you don't actually need to wrap your function in the return this.each(). This is used to pass on the collection of elements you're modifying to the next method in the chain. Since you're just trying to return a value, just use the code you have without wrapping it in return this.each().

Comment: I was going to at first but since I found the correct answer, I felt I should just add a comment with the correct answer explaining why my answer was wrong and how it was related to the correct answer.